# Dojo Calendar Not Destroying On My Connect

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

Hey all, this is weird. This widget will not destroy onHide. I know the event is firing because I have placed debug code within the function that is ran. I have no idea why this won't work... it is clearly documented in the API. My code is below:

```
            var formitem=new dijit.Calendar({
                name:this.formitems.calendaritems[i].id,
                id: this.formitems.calendaritems[i].id
            },
            dojo.create('dd',null,
            this.lineitems));
            dojo.connect(myself.dialog, 'onHide', function() {
                formitem.destroy();
            });
```

I keep getting the error the widget is already registered, however if the destroy function is supposed to work correctly then it is supposed to destroy the instance of it. Please help.

Comment: where do you add the Calendar (formitem) to the page?

Answer (score 1):

"the widget is already registered" error results from using a ID that's already been used. If you **have** to set the id, ensure that you never use the same one twice. But I would just remove that line where you set the id. Somewhere along the line you are recreating the Calendar. It's possible that you are deleting it as expected but its trying to recreate.

Note this is a bit of guess, since the example seems to be missing code that is relevant to your problem.